# game center report score not working

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

gameCenterManager
[gameCenterManager reportScore:score_value forCategory:@"123"];

not working?? whenever I send a score through the above line , when I run this applciation and open gdb then Missed Method is saying in the callDeletgete

how can I solve it

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some more code?

Comment: sure  [self.gameCenterManager reportScore:score_value forCategory:@"123"];       "I am using GKTapper project"
  and through reportScore function   - (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category 
{
 GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease]; 
 scoreReporter.value = score;
 [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
  {
   [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
  }];
}

Answer (score 1):

my report score codees are like this:

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"123"] autorelease];
                scoreReporter.value = 123456;

                [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        // handle the reporting error
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with the above code. It updates my default leaderboard each time and works correctly but the other two of my leaderboards it has only let me post my first score :S